# Why is system freezing when i do recursive spinlock in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, synchronization, linux-device-driver

I know the linux kernel doesn't support recursive spinlocks, and it will deadlock.

I wrote a sample code to see the behavior and even if i have multiple CPU's the system is freezing. Is this the expected behavior

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/spinlock.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

DEFINE_SPINLOCK(my_lock);

static int __init test_hello_init(void)
{
    spin_lock(&my_lock);
    spin_lock(&my_lock);
    pr_info("Starting critical region\n");
    pr_info("Ending critical region\n");
    spin_unlock(&my_lock);
    return -1;
}

static void __exit test_hello_exit(void)
{
}

module_init(test_hello_init);
module_exit(test_hello_exit);

watchdog: BUG: soft lookup. - CPU stuck for 22s!
```

Comment: I am confused. You say you know that it deadlocks, then you say that it deadlocks, and then you ask whether it is correct that it deadlocks?

Comment: My question, why is the system hanging, even one cpu is deadlocked?

Answer (score 1):

Acquiring spinlock prevents the thread from being *preempted*. So CPU wouldn't switch to another thread until given thread releases all spinlocks it hold.

This is exactly what the error message

> BUG: soft lookup. - CPU stuck for 22s!

means: CPU has not switched for 22 seconds.

When CPU switches to other thread, it performs some additional tasks which are required for OS to work. This is why it is crucial to not hold spinlocks (and other things which prevents preemtion) too long.